# How to import a python file at the start of ipython notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I want to lunch my `iPython notebook` kernel remotely and have it import a `setup.py` file automatically at startup. I have tried

```
python notebook --no-browser
```

one of the output message is:

```
Using existing profile dir: u'/path/to/profile_default'
```

such directory contains a `startup` folder which contains my `setup.py` file.
Unfortunately the content of the file is not imported as expected.

I am looking for the `notebook` equivalent of the `-c` option for the standard shell.

In case is relevant, this is still on Python 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new ipython profile,

```
$ ipython profile create foo
```

Edit the `ipython_config.py` file it generates, you can locate it with:

```
$ ipython locate profile foo
```

After

```
c = get_confg()
```

Add

```
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = ['import setup']
```

Then start the notebook with the `--profile` argument,

```
$ ipython notebook --no-browser --profile=foo
```

If you don't want to create a profile, then you can add this via command-line by using `--ClassName.attribute=...`

```
$ ipython notebook --no-browser --InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines="['import setup']"
```

More information on ipython profiles: http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/config/intro.html

Comment: That's interesting, but since I need to create a make file to start this process up, I am trying to minimize the amount of manual work. Is there a way to pass the code directly via command line at start up time?

Comment: If you're wanting to distribute this, then you can distribute the profile alongside your Makefile.

Comment: So I guess is not possible to pass arbitrary code via the command line?

Comment: @meto Turns out you can pass in any configuration option through the command-line by using `--ClassName.attribute=...`. I have updated my answer to give an example.